# Can't connect to nodejs server in docker container after settting USER

Tags: node.js, docker, electron, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that works fine when running as root.  If I add a non-privileged user it runs:

`docker ps`
(I changed the container names)

```
f63a4ae42ba9        nonroot   "sh /app/docker-st..."   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:3002->3002/tcp   nonroot
4bd547b40246        root      "sh /app/docker-st..."   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:3003->3002/tcp   root
```

But I do not get a server response.  It looks like it can connect however.

```
wget http://localhost:3002/stats
--2017-07-20 14:40:27--  http://localhost:3002/stats
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|::1|:3002... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.
```

The container running as root works fine:

```
wget http://localhost:3003/stats
--2017-07-20 14:40:31--  http://localhost:3003/stats
Resolving localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost|::1|:3003... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5866 (5.7K) [application/json]
Saving to: ‘stats.1
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
  libgconf2-4 libxss1 libxtst6 libnss3 libasound2 xvfb dbus-x11 libgtk2.0-common \
  imagemagick ghostscript poppler-utils && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV NODE_ENV="production"
COPY ./package.json /app/
RUN npm install

ENV \
ELECTRONEXPORT_HOST="0.0.0.0" \
ELECTRONEXPORT_PORT="3002" \
ELECTRONEXPORT_DATA="/data" \
ELECTRONEXPORT_LOGDIR="/var/log/spider_export" \
ELECTRONEXPORT_LOGSIZE="1" \
DEBUG="electronpdf*,pdf*"

COPY docker-start.sh start.js /app/
COPY src/ /app/src

RUN groupadd -r sbe && \
useradd --no-log-init -r -g sbe sbe && \
chown -R sbe:sbe /app && \
chmod -R 755 /app

# Run as a non-privileged user
USER sbe

EXPOSE 3002

CMD ["sh", "/app/docker-start.sh"]
```

And these are the lines that were added that present the issue:

```
RUN groupadd -r sbe && \
useradd --no-log-init -r -g sbe sbe && \
chown -R sbe:sbe /app && \
chmod -R 755 /app

# Run as a non-privileged user
USER sbe
```

**Edit**: I have found this error in the log

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Failed to get 'appData' path
    at Error (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/browser/init.js:149:39)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:402:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:157:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by reordering the npm install.  It seems that electron puts things somewhere which my `chmod` was not hitting.

By changing the user before npm install the issues is resolved

```
RUN groupadd -r sbe && \
useradd --no-log-init -m -r -g sbe sbe && \
chown -R sbe:sbe /app && \
chmod -R 755 /app

# Run as a non-privileged user (inside the container)
USER sbe
ENV NODE_ENV="production"
COPY ./package.json /app/
RUN npm install
```